# send mail from joomla to gmail address

Tags: email, joomla, gmail, send

I'm new with Joomla and I'm currently trying to set up a contact form. I searched on several forums but I didn't find an answer to my problem. First thing I want to know is if it's possible to send an email with a local web server. Secondly, is it possible to send the mails to a gmail adress and, if yes, what parameters - and where- do I have to change.

Joomla Version: 3.2.2

Comment: What localhost are you using?

Comment: You can send e-mails from localhost, but you need to set up your server properly. What software are you using?

Comment: I'm using server2go. So you don't think the problem comes from the joomla configuration ?